# admob fill rate issues for Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, admob, ads

I recently decided to put ads on my android application. The issue I'm seeing is that I only get served "one" ad when I turn on the app for the first time. After that, I never get to see an ad anywhere else. It just stays blank!

According to admob, I'm getting a 100% fill rate and that doesn't make any sense.

Here is my logcat output.

```
02-25 10:53:24.528: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(8346): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-25 10:53:24.548: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(8346): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-25 10:53:24.548: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(8346): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-25 10:53:24.608: D/dalvikvm(1004): GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 18% free 18014K/21928K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 18ms
02-25 10:53:25.278: I/Ads(8346): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-25 10:53:25.278: I/Ads(8346): Ad finished loading.
02-25 10:53:25.298: I/chromium(8346): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
02-25 10:53:25.318: I/chromium(8346): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
02-25 10:53:35.268: E/qcom_sensors_hal(767): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
02-25 10:53:48.698: I/Ads(8346): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
02-25 10:53:48.698: I/Ads(8346): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on.

Here's my xml layout.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/video"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="stuff"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Here is my code

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Note: I use that code in oncreate for an activity and in onactivitycreated() for my fragments. I use the same exact adunitID for all ads in my app.

Admob says that it has already served over 10 thousand impressions with a 100% fill rate.

Answer (score 1):

The log seems to state that the AdView is not visible:

```
02-25 10:53:48.698: I/Ads(8346): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

You haven't posted enough of your layout or your code to work out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add unitId and adSize programmatically not from XML like [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) google code example.